# $(2^{x+4})-(x^{x+2})=3$ find the value of x kindly help with step by step solution

Tags: exponential-function

My teacher suggested $-2$ answer but I don't know how it would come kindly some one explain with step by step solution thank you

Comment: Do you mean to solve the question $2^{x+4} - 2^{x+2} = 3$ instead? If so, you can factor out a $2^{x+2}$ on the left hand side.

Comment: which level of mathematics are you learning at school @saria ?

Comment: I think the answer given by @Mohammad Riazi-Kermani is the proper way given your level.

Comment: I am learning business mathematics and it is elementary level question according to teacher

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $-2$ for $x$ in $$(2^{x+4})-(x^{x+2})=3$$  and you get  $$(2^{-2+4})-((-2)^{0})=3$$  That is $4-1 =3$

Thus $x=-2$ is a solution if we allow $(-2)^0 =1$

This is of course trial and error method which dose not carry much weight.
An analytic solution does not seem possible.

Numerical methods gives a solution of $$x\approx 2.6735105$$ as a positive solution.

Comment: I don`t think that $$x=-2 $$ is solution because we assume that $$ x>0$$

Comment: You are correct. I do not know why the teacher suggested that as a solution.